# bash / sed: trim first and last sequence of specified character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

1) By using sed how to remove all sequence of colons on the end and begin of the string. For example change "::trim:::test::" to "trim:::test".

```
echo "::trim:::test::" | sed 's/:*//'
```

2) How to do the same using this syntax:

```
test="::trim:::test::"
echo ${test%:}
```

Comment: `echo "::trim:::test::" | sed -E 's/^:+|:+$//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning of string is matched by `^`, end of string by `$` in sed:

```
sed 's/^:*\|:*$//g'
```

Parameter expansions `#` and `%` only work at one end of the string and can't be combined, so we need two commands:

```
shopt -s extglob
test=${test##+(:)}
test=${test%%+(:)}
```

The `extglob` option enables the `+(:)` which corresponds to `:+` in regular expressions, i.e. it matches : one or more times. The `#` and `%` are doubled to match greedily.